# Php - En un formulario Edit, ¿Cómo hacer para obtener los valores de tabla mysql por defecto?

Tags: php, html, date

Tengo una lista de pagos en mysql. Necesito que en mi formulario me llene con los valores de mi tabla por defecto:
[image: Listado de pagos]
Este es parte de mi código donde tomo los datos:

```
<?php
        // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
        $nik = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_GET["nik"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM fees WHERE id='$nik'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0){
            header("Location: list.php");
        }else{
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
        }
        if(isset($_POST['save'])){
            $fee_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["fee_date"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $fee      = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["fee"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $discount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["discount"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $method   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["method"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $p_month      = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["p_month"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $p_year = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["p_year"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $pay_type     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["pay_type"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
           
            
            $update = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE fees SET fee_date='$fee_date', fee='$fee', discount='$discount', method='$method', payment_month= '$month', payment_year='$year', payment_type='$pay_type', user_auth='$user', updated_at='$timestamp' WHERE id='$nik'") or die(mysqli_error());
            if($update){
                header("Location: edit.php?nik=".$nik."&pesan=sukses");
            }else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Error, data could not be saved.</div>';
            }
        }
        
        if(isset($_GET['pesan']) == 'sukses'){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>The data has been saved successfully.</div>';
        }
        ?>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" name='MyForm'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Payment Date</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="date" name="fee_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row ['fee_date'])); ?>" class="input-group date form-control"  placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Fee ($)</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="number" name="fee" value="<?php echo $row ['fee']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" step="0.10"  required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Discount ($)</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="number" name="discount" value="<?php echo $row ['discount']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Discount" step="0.10">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Luego esta es la parte del código donde edito los datos:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Month</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select name="p_month" class="form-control">
            <?php
            $p_month = !empty($_GET['p_month']) ? $_GET['p_month'] : 0;
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 11; ++$i) {
                $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
                $label = date('F ', $time);
                $value = date('m', $time);
                $selected = ($value == $p_month) ? ' selected=true' : '';
                printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $value, $selected, $label);
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Year</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        </select>
        <select name="p_year" class="form-control">
            <?php
            $p_year = !empty($_GET['p_year']) ? $_GET['p_year'] : 0;
            for ($i = -1; $i <= 1; ++$i) {
                $time = strtotime(sprintf('-%d years', $i));
                $value = date('Y', $time);
                $label = date('Y ', $time);
                $selected = ($value == $p_year) ? ' selected=true' : '';
                printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $value, $selected, $label);
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select name="pay_type" class="form-control">
            <option value="0"> ----- </option>
            <option value="1">Completion</option>
            <option value="2">Proportionate</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quisiera que los datos, al momento de editar seal los que me aparece en el listado de arriba.
Buscando en stackoverflow encontré estos códigos para formar combobox con mes y año, pero al momento de editar se ve así (son 4 capturas de un mismo formulario):

[image: Edit]
Es decir, en el formulario marcado debería destar: Month = May, Year = 2021 y Type = Completion.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor aclara tu problema... dices tener problemas con mes, año y tipo... CUAL es el problema ??

Comment: Si, por favor, perdón si no explique bien. El código publicado es para editar los valores. Pero cuando quiero editar, no me trae los valores de mi tabla (tal como los tengo en el listado de arriba), sino que me muestra otros valores (de las 4 capturas, es el primero). Ese formulario deberia tener Month=May, Year=2021 y Type = Completion. Gracias y disculpa de nuevo.

Comment: Pues primero, hay que ver donde estás rescatando esos valores. Ya que, los mostrados en la imagen, no es un error.. son los valores default cuando NO HAY DATOS. Corri tu codigo y tengo las mismas imagenes, asi que hay que ver de donde traes eso.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, he agregado en mi pregunta parte del código donde tomos los datos.

Comment: Por que si estas enviando con POST... tratas de recibir GET ?? ... al inicio de la pagina que recibe, has un `echo $_POST["method"];` a ver que te sale

Comment: Disculpame, estoy aprendiendo. Este es el resultado: Notice: Undefined index: method in ...

Comment: Ok... no estás ni enviando ni recibiendo los datos. Te recomiendo verificar que puedes enviar y recibir al menos 1 dato, de una pag a otra.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, tal vez no me explique bien pero las dos partes de código es del mismo script... edit.php

Comment: Si, pero no estás recibiendo los datos POST... por eso no cargas nada

Comment: Disculpa, los valores  fee_date (Pament Date), fee, discoun, method, si me carga bien, solo no me carga 3 datos, month, year y type

Comment: Entonces que hacemos, nos quedamos mirando como esos 3 no funcionan o verás que les sucede ?? Hazle un var_dump a la variable por que por algo no obtienes el date como quieres.

Comment: Sip, el problema es con el mes y el año que quería que fuera un combobox, voy a segur buscando alguna alternativa donde pueda usar combobox, pero que por defecto quede el valor que lee de la tabla.

Comment: La forma mas sencilla es tener cargados los datos de antemano...